# How to configure AWS Amplify build notifications to include commit/PR message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, slack, amazon-sns

I am using AWS amplify to host my react app. The source code is on GitHub.

I have a lambda listening to [AWS SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/notifications.html) and pushes a message to Slack to inform about the deployment status.

I want to achieve that the Slack notification includes PR name (or commit message if it was directly pushed to the branch instead of merging the PR).

I cannot find the commit message/PR name within SNS message. Is it possible to get this information retrieved?

The SNS event I get looks like

```
{
"Records": [
    {
        "EventSource": "aws:sns",
        "EventVersion": "1.0",
        "EventSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:xx-central-x:xxxxxxx:amplify-xxxxxx_main:aaaaaaaa-2189-bbbb-8ca3-cccccccccccc",
        "Sns": {
            "Type": "Notification",
            "MessageId": "aaaaaaaa-107b-bbbb-a47b-cccccccccccc",
            "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:xx-central-x:001700307000:amplify-xxxxxx_main",
            "Subject": null,
            "Message": "\"Build notification from the AWS Amplify Console for app: https://main.xxxxx.amplifyapp.com/. Your build status is STARTED. Go to https://link.com to view details on your build. \"",
            "Timestamp": "2021-08-05T08:36:37.919Z",
            "SignatureVersion": "1",
            "Signature": "DaPEZM6+WumrAg==",
            "SigningCertUrl": "https://sns.xx-central-x.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-xxxxx.pem",
            "UnsubscribeUrl": "https://sns.xx-central-x.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:xx-central-x:xxxxx:amplify-xxxxxx_main:aaaaaaaa-2189-bbbb-8ca3-cccccccccccc",
            "MessageAttributes": {}
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: What is the SNS messages you get so far?

Comment: @shimo I have edited the question to include the SNS message which I get

Comment: SNS message above is about the Amplify build only. Not sure but you can use `GetCommentsForPullRequest` method in the Lambda function and connect the results.